# Compiler optimization of strcmp I don't understand, against a constant string

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, strcmp

In order to improve my binary exploitation skills, and deepen my understanding in low level environments I tried solving challenges in `pwnable.kr`, The first challenge- called `fd` has the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char buf[32];
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]){
        if(argc<2){
                printf("pass argv[1] a number\n");
                return 0;
        }
        int fd = atoi( argv[1] ) - 0x1234;
        int len = 0;
        len = read(fd, buf, 32);
        if(!strcmp("LETMEWIN\n", buf)){
                printf("good job :)\n");
                system("/bin/cat flag");
                exit(0);
        }
        printf("learn about Linux file IO\n");
        return 0;

}
```

I used `objdump -S -g ./fd` in order to disassemble it, and I got confused, because insteaad of calling a strcmp function. It just compared the strings without calling it. 
This is the assembly code im talking about:

```
 80484c6:   e8 05 ff ff ff          call   80483d0 <atoi@plt> 
 80484cb:   2d 34 12 00 00          sub    eax,0x1234 
 ; eax = atoi( argv[1] ) - 0x1234;
 ; initialize fd=eax
 80484d0:   89 44 24 18             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],eax
 ; initialize len
 80484d4:   c7 44 24 1c 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x0

 ; Set up read variables
 80484db:   00 
 80484dc:   c7 44 24 08 20 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],0x20 ; read 32 bytes
 80484e3:   00 
 80484e4:   c7 44 24 04 60 a0 04    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x804a060 ; buf variable address
 80484eb:   08 
 80484ec:   8b 44 24 18             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x18]
 80484f0:   89 04 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax ; fd variable
 80484f3:   e8 78 fe ff ff          call   8048370 <read@plt> 

 80484f8:   89 44 24 1c             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],eax
 80484fc:   ba 46 86 04 08          mov    edx,0x8048646 ; "LETMEWIN\n" address
 8048501:   b8 60 a0 04 08          mov    eax,0x804a060 ; buf address
 8048506:   b9 0a 00 00 00          mov    ecx,0xa ; what is this?
 ; strcmp starts here?
 804850b:   89 d6                   mov    esi,edx
 804850d:   89 c7                   mov    edi,eax
 804850f:   f3 a6                   repz cmps BYTE PTR ds:[esi],BYTE PTR es:[edi] ; <------- ?STRCMP?
```

The things I don't understand are:

1. Where is the `strcmp` call? And why is it like that?
2. What does this `8048506:    b9 0a 00 00 00 mov ecx,0xa` do?

Comment: @alinsoar: That's not what's happening here, though. This is a regular in-lined string comparison. To the OP: the 10 moved to `ecx` is the repeat count for the string compare.

Comment: `repz cmps` is what compares the strings.  Look it up in the Intel manuals!

Comment: If you compile with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you should try `gcc -O2 -S -Wall -fverbose-asm src.c` then look inside the generated assembler code `src.s`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler inlined `strcmp` against a known-length string using [`repe cmpsb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz) which implements memcmp.

It loads into register `esi` the address of the constant literal string "LETMEWIN\n". Note that the length of this string is 10 (with the '\0' at the end).
Then it loads the address of `buf` into `edi` register, then it calls for the x86 instruction:

```
repz cmps BYTE PTR ds:[esi],BYTE PTR es:[edi]
```

[`repz`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-4693/instructionset-64/index.html) repeats the following instruction as long as zero flag is set and up to the number of times stored in `ecx` (this explains you the `mov    ecx,0xa ; what is this?`).

The repeated instruction is [`cmps`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-4693/instructionset-59/index.html) which compares strings (byte by byte) and automatically increases the pointers by 1 on each iteration.
When the compared bytes are equal, it sets the zero flag.

So per your questions:

> Where is the strcmp call? And why is it like that?

No explicit call for `strcmp`, it is optimized out and replaced with inlined code:

```
 80484fc:   ba 46 86 04 08          mov    edx,0x8048646 ; "LETMEWIN\n" address
 8048501:   b8 60 a0 04 08          mov    eax,0x804a060 ; buf address
 8048506:   b9 0a 00 00 00          mov    ecx,0xa ; number of bytes to compare
 804850b:   89 d6                   mov    esi,edx
 804850d:   89 c7                   mov    edi,eax
 804850f:   f3 a6                   repz cmps BYTE PTR ds:[esi],BYTE PTR es:[edi] ;
```

Actually it misses the part where it should check if the returned value of `strcmp` is zero or not. I think you just didn't copy it here. There probably should be something like `je ...` / `jz ...` / `jne ...` / `jnz ...` right after the `repz ...` line.

> What does this 8048506:    b9 0a 00 00 00 mov ecx,0xa do?

It sets the maximum number of bytes to compare.

Comment: Fun fact: `repe cmpsb` is not fast, and this strcmp strategy isn't great.  [Coaxing GCC to emit REPE CMPSB](//stackoverflow.com/q/49375094).  And gcc used to even inline strlen as `repne scasb` at -O1, leading to a huge performance downside for code that used it on very long strings: [Why is this code 6.5x slower with optimizations enabled?](//stackoverflow.com/q/55563598)

Comment: @PeterCordes right... comparing memory byte by byte on 32bit or 64bit systems is  not efficient at all however it might be good enough for 10 bytes strings like in this case.

Comment: There are better ways, e.g. 3x `cmp`-immediate/`jne` to compare in 4-byte chunks.  (But that has more total branching).  Or two unaligned `movq xmm0, [eax]` loads that line up with the start and end of the buffer, respectively.  Or maybe movq/movhps to do two overlapping 8-byte loads into one register, for `pcmpeqb` against a 16-byte constant.

Comment: SSE4.2 `pcmpistri` is useful if you know you can overread the source without risk of crossing into an unmapped page and faulting.  But in that case you might as well just use `pcmpeqb` / `pmovmskb` and AND away the bits you don't care about.  e.g. `and eax, (1<<10) - 1` / `cmp eax, (1<<10) - 1`

Comment: @PeterCordes definitely. However it requires the target CPU to support SSE4.2, I don't know with what `cpu` flags it was compiled... on the other hand even it were compiled with such flags, I doubt GCC would produce anything similar to what you suggested.

Comment: Like I said, if you could use `pcmpistri` safely, it would still be better *not* to.  SSE2 `pcmpeqb` plus masking away the high bits of the `pmovmskb` result would be faster.  On Skylake `pcmpistri` has 10 cycle latency and costs 3 uops vs. 1 uop / 1c for `pcmpeqb`.  And you're right, gcc doesn't know this strategy for inlining `strcmp`.  That's my point: it *should* use a better strategy like it does for `memcmp` against a constant.  But it's hard unless you check for the pointer being near the end of a page.  e.g. a pointer to a `'\0'` as the last byte of a page is safe for `repe cmpsb`.